# $2yy^{\prime} = y^2 +x -1 , y(0) = 1$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

$$2yy^{\prime} = y^2 +x -1 ,\ \ \ \ \ y(0) = 1$$

I have tried the substitution $u = y^2 + x -1 $ but i dont know how i get $u^{\prime}$

Comment: Differentiate both sides is all you have to do. What do you get when you do?

Comment: $u^{\prime} = 2yy^{\prime} + 1$?

Comment: Yes thats corect Maria. Substitute $u$ and $u'$  in the differential equation and solve. It's a separable differential equation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could also recognize $2yy'$ as $(y^2)'$ so that your differential equation is

$$(y^2)' = y^2 + x - 1.$$

Letting $u = y^2$, you get

$$ u' = u + x - 1 $$

which is easily solved and then you can solve for $y$ from there.

Answer (score 0):

$$u = y^2 + x -1$$
Just differentiate:
$$u'=2yy'+1$$
And substitute in the differential equation  $2yy'=u'-1$. Note that an easier substitution could be $u=y^2+x$ and $u'=2yy'+1$.
$$2yy' = y^2 +x -1$$
$$2yy'+1=y^2+x$$
$$(y^2+x)'=y^2+x$$
$$u'=u$$
This is a separable differential equation.

Answer (score 0):

$2yy^{\prime} = y^2 +x -1 $ , rewrite it as $$y^{\prime}-\frac{1}{2}y =\frac{1}{2}(x -1)y^{-1}$$

This is a Bernoulli differential equation with $n=-1$ let $z=y^{1-n}.$ Can you continue?